# Issue in populating ajax data into table via ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to populate a table on receiving JSON data on an Ajax get from Mongo DB.

I am able to see the received data in alert. But my table is not populated.
I am clicking the retrive button to get the data.

JS code:

```
   $scope.retrive = function()
    {
      $scope.people =[];
            $.ajax({
                    url     : "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/geolocation/collections/boom?apiKey=veTqID_gkb74tG-yL4MGcS1p2RRBP1Pf",
                    type    : "GET",
                            dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                    $scope.people = JSON.stringify(data);
                    alert($scope.people);
                            //alert("status = "+data.status+"descripttion"+data.description);
                            //console.log(data);
                              //document.getElementById("n1").innerHTML = data[0].name;
                  //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                              tableCreate(data);
                            //alert(data[0].name);
                              //var json = JSON.parse(data);
                            //alert(json.name);
                    }
                });
    };


         }]);
```

HTML code:

```
  <div>
      <table>
    <tr>
        <th>ITEM</th>
        <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
        <th>QUANTITY</th>
        <th>LOCATION</th>
        <th>CATEGORY</th>

    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
        <td>{{person.Item}}</td>
        <td>{{person.Description}}</td>
        <td>{{person.Quantity}}</td>        
        <td>{{person.Location}}</td>
        <td>{{person.Category}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
    </div>
```

Here is the Plunker Link :

http://plnkr.co/edit/OKzTApbW7ii8R0EMrOyx?p=preview

Comment: Why you are using jQuery ajax? You can use `$http` service build in angular.

Comment: whats not working. I tried the plunker and clicked on retrieve data and the table was populated. Can you explain what exactly is the issue?

Comment: Well the table that gets populated is made in JS. That works fine.I am trying Angular table with ng-repeat. Check plunker , i saved it now. That is not getting populated.

Comment: @NavalJoshi see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try is like this:

**Note (Just a tip ): Putting API keys within stack overflow questions is not a good idea. Keep the API key private as any body can use your key and you could blocked out from the service due to unauthorised usage.**

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
  myApp.controller('projectController', function($scope, $http){


  $scope.userDetails = [];


  $scope.test = function(){

        console.log("getting user projects, please wait ......");
   // Simple GET request example (passing data) :
       $http.get("https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/geolocation/collections/boom?apiKey=YOUR-API-KEY", {

   }).
   success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       // this callback will be called asynchronously
       // when the response is available
       console.log("");
       $scope.userDetails = data;


   }).
   error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       // called asynchronously if an error occurs
       // or server returns response with an error status.
   });
  };

});
```

Heres a working Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/xoFuBa695E7O1g6gTcm4?p=preview

**UPDATED Plunker**

http://plnkr.co/edit/7E4PKbnqBDwsVptIaJ1Q?p=preview

Comment: Well i tried , i am able to get the data in my function, But when i put it in userDetails. I am unable to get it inside ng-repeat .Check my plunker.

Comment: @NavalJoshi see my updated plunker in the answer above. Also try reading through the link attached there were a few mistakes in your code. Go through the basics. It will help. https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: Hey sorry for not replying.. it did not worked, though your example did, but still unable to fix my peice of code.Ok here is a plunk - a sample code of the problem i am facing - http://plnkr.co/edit/ATBCs0gSC269k2IROTQM?p=preview [trying to populate table from an Ajax received Data]